# Choice of model for different proxy of explanatory variables?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error, model

Let's suppose the true regression model is: 
$$Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$$
where, $Y$ is dependent variable, $X$ is independent variable, and $\epsilon$ is residuals.

My objective is to estimate beta from the empirical data but the problem is that $X$ is unknown and what we know is proxy of $X$. Now suppose that we have two proxy for $X$ are available, $X_1$ and $X_2$, and the corresponding empirical models are:

**Model 1**
$$Y = \hat{\alpha_1} + \hat{\beta_1}X_1 + \hat{\epsilon}$$

**Model 2**
$$Y = \hat{\alpha_2} + \hat{\beta_2}X_2 + \hat{\epsilon}$$

I just wanted to know how to determine which $\hat{\beta_i}_{\{i=1,2\}}$ is better estimator of $\beta$? Should we use standard error of estimated beta (choose with lower standard error) or $R^2$(model with high $R^2$)?

---

Such problems commonly arise in finance. To estimate beta of security it is require to regress security returns($Y$) on market returns($X$). Since, there are various indices available to measure market return, a common problem arise which index should be used to estimate $\beta$?

Comment: Would there be any utility or usefulness in fitting the sum of 1/2 of each, that is, fitting y = (a1 + B1X1)/2 + (a2 + B2X2)/2? Just curious.

Comment: I do not know either this is practically feasible or not ?